# Texmaker and TeXnicCenter.

Tags: editors, texniccenter, texmaker

What are relative merits of these two Latex editors:
[TeXnicCenter](http://www.texniccenter.org/) and [Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/)?
What are their shortcomings to prefer one over other?

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270121/best-latex-editor-for-windows) SO question.

Comment: Personally, I would recommend [TeXworks](http://tug.org/texworks/) over both of these programs. The goal of TeXworks is to offer the same functionality and look & feel for all major operating systems. This consistency may come in *very* handy when you are TeXing at different computers.

Comment: related question: [Editors supporting unicode](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14876/editors-supporting-unicode)

Comment: TeXworks cannot handle a project.

Comment: What do you mean, @Herbert?
In your opinion what is better TexnicCenter, TexStudio or something else such as Bakoma or Kile?

Answer (score 14):

- Texmaker is cross-platform, working on Windows, Linux and Mac OS X while TeXnicCenter works only on Windows.
- Texmaker supports Unicode, for TeXnicCenter it's been announced for the new version.
- Texmaker provides a built-in pdf viewer and can launch external viewers. TeXnicCenter supports any external pdf viewer. Both provide forward and inverse search with pdf and dvi.
- Note, for Texmaker there's a fork [TeXstudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/) (formerly named TexmakerX) with some improvements.

Comment: I learned about both from your blog, thanks.

Comment: Does Texmaker need some build system in case of separate PDF figures, many separate files, etc?

Comment: You could work with several files and declare one of them to be the "Master  file".

Comment: TeXnicCenter does provide UTF support.

Answer (score 4):

Just a minor addition to Stefan's answer, but something that might not be mentioned in other places:

I like to use MiKTeX with the **`-auxiliary-files`** option, which puts all the files created during compilation (except for the final pdf/dvi/ps) in another directory. **Texmaker** doesn't work well with this, i.e. compilation works, but it **doesn't find the .log file in a remote directory**, so errors and warnings can't be displayed. There is a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/detail?id=97) for this; I have no idea how quickly such things get fixed.

TeXnicCenter worked just fine with the `-auxiliary-files` option.

Since I now need the Unicode support that TeXnicCenter doesn't offer, I've settled for having the auxiliary files cluttering up everything, and ocasionally getting rid of them via `latexmk -c foo.tex`.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I prefer [Winshell](http://winshell.de) when I'm working on Windows. A main sticking point is the possibility to better manage my papers by organizing all files for each paper into a project, so I can quickly switch between the papers and see which file belongs to which project (I like to use a large number of .tex files -- one per section/subsection, if applicable). WinShell also has a BibTeX manager, if you need it.

One drawback is that it's not open-source (but is completely free), so if you have strong feelings about this, you should probably look elsewhere.

I'm also checking regularly the progress on [TeXWorks](http://tug.org/texworks/), which is under development, but has a built-in PDF reader and synchronized scrolling of both the source and the rendered document. It lacks a lot of other features that I'd like to have --- notably, file organization, that I mentioned above.

Comment: TeXworks allows convenient and quick work, that's why I'm daily using it.

Comment: It's good to note that TeXworks is included in the default MiKTeX 2.9 installation.