# Editors supporting unicode

Tags: unicode, editors

For some reason it seems that my favourite editor TeXnicCenter doesn't support unicode (correct me please if I'm wrong, which wouldn't be the first time).

Can anyone recommend an editor which does, for Windows platform? Simplicity is appreciated.

Comment: There are still editors out there not supporting Unicode?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Latex Editors/IDEs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides)

Comment: All of the cross-platform LaTeX editors support Unicode.  See this question [Latex Editors/IDEs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) for various pointers. Two good ones to try would be TeXWorks and TeXMakerX.

Comment: @Caramdir: yes, seems like a duplicate, but I thought that the question about TeXnicCenter not supporting unicode deserved a separate answer. Anyway, if this is truly a duplicate, let me know so I can delete my answer to close the question.

Comment: @Gonzales: The actual question is a duplicate (imo), but I didn't know that the implicit question in the first statement has an answer (i.e. the first part of your answer). Anyway, having answers doesn't prevent a question from being closed, so there is no need to remove your answer.

Comment: @Caramdir: it's Gonzalo and not Gonzales ;-)

Comment: @Gonzalo: sorry!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the TeXnicCenter site, there'a an alpha version that supports unicode: [TeXnicCenter 2.0 Alpha 1](http://www.texniccenter.org/news/122-texniccenter-20-alpha-1).

If you are willing to change your editor, perhaps the answers to this question can be useful for you: [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/3954).

I personally use [TeXworks](http://www.tug.org/texworks/) (I use it under Linux, but it is multiplataform, so you can also use it on Windows machines).

Comment: Texniccenter is now in alpha 4, http://sourceforge.net/projects/texniccenter/files/TeXnicCenter%20Alpha/2Alpha4/TXCSetup_2Alpha4_Win32.exe/download

Answer (score 6):

If you prefer simplicity, [TeXworks](http://www.tug.org/texworks/) has my recommendations (it also comes bundled with MiKTeX).

Another excellent editor which supports unicode is [Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) - it might be considered even simpler to use because it offers wizards for common tasks.

Answer (score 2):

see last column in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TeX_editors

Answer (score 2):

Folks, there is only one editor, which is as mighty as LaTeX is: Emacs, with the AUCTeX-Package.

Don't garble your workflow by using one of this half-baked, GUI-dominated and buggy newcomers. Emacs has been around for more than 20 years.

I will retag this question.

---

Edit: Recently I found out that Emacs even can use the back of Word documents! Think of all the people who only work on the side of the document which is shown on the screen! What a waste of resources.

Comment: Tags are about questions, not answers!

Comment: @JosephWright And he asked for Emacs, though he did not know!

Comment: Well, that's your view :-) I'd say he's asked for TeXworks, but that's because it's the editor I use. But then I upvoted some of the other cases:-)

Comment: @JosephWright What a terrible heresy. I abstain from re-retaging for today, but I never will understand why people like you, professional TeXies, can bear that. There's only so much you can take.

Comment: Bah. Emacs is clearly overkill. You should use nothing less minimal than [nano](http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.0/faq.html#5.3). Clearly.

Comment: Yeah. We have `sed`, who needs more?

Comment: Pfft.  "Editor"?  I just toggle in my dvi directly at the front panel.

Comment: In all seriousness I do occasionally use nano for LaTeX. If I need to tweak a paper on the move I ssh into my server with my smart phone, and let Dropbox handle everything else. I wouldn't really recommend it though.

Comment: to learn how REAL programers do it, read here: http://xkcd.com/378/

Comment: This joke *has been* funny. Or maybe it has. What is sure is that now it is threadbare.
I use emacs but seriously this kind of answer and comment have so much duplicates over the Internet that they begin to resemble spam.

Comment: @AlfredM. I agree, that xkcd comic is very old, but reading it and afterwards re-reading the answer and comments here, I am still amused. A little

Answer (score 1):

[TeXstudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/) is best Unicode Editor in arena right now.

Comment: The reviews on the sourceforge page are strongly disagreeing with you.

Comment: @percusse The reviews on the sourceforge page are not about RTL issue. TeXstudio is feature-rich, but is not so stable.

Comment: Indeed it looks like so. But to be able to use those features you need the editor to be running. In case of instabilities, the features can not contribute to your workflow.