# German character not rendered to pdf

Tags: characters, input-encodings, german

I just started using LaTeX, and need to use the character "ü". I already have this in main file :

```
%%% Sprach- und zeichensatzspezifische Pakete
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{array}
```

where I believe the `latin9` `inputenc` will allow me to show **ü** in the PDF file. However, when I type `pdflatex main`, I get the PDF file, where the word *für* is rendered as **fÃŒr**

There is no error, and the package is already there (if not, for sure it will prompt me for error message). How to render this "ü" in PDF? Would appreciate any answer.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to get the character to work, but you can just use `\"u` to get a "ü" in the pdf.

Answer (score 14):

Instead of changing every single umlaut manualy, you should better use a complete utf8 workflow, as Jouni suggested. This will save you a lot of work!
Just replace the lines you posted (and maybe parts of your documentclass) with the following:

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    ngerman
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{babel}

\begin{document}
  Write üöäß directly!
  And é and è and çñâøæð.
\end{document}
```

Using UTF8 makes your life easier, 
but it means you need a [UTF8 capable editor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14876/editors-supporting-unicode). 
Personally, I really like [Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/),
which is UTF8 capable, has a nice and simple GUI and is available for free for Windows, Linux and Mac OS.
And you need to [save your files as UTF8](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19427/how-do-i-change-the-encoding-of-my-files).

Maybe you'll also find the following questions helpful:

- [Using inputenc package for cp1252 encoding](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35451/using-inputenc-package-for-cp1252-encoding)
- [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides)
- [Why should I use \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664/why-should-i-use-usepackaget1fontenc)
- [Latin Modern vs cm-super?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/latin-modern-vs-cm-super)
- [What packages do people load by default in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553/what-packages-do-people-load-by-default-in-latex)
- [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex)
- [How to use biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26516/how-to-use-biber)

Answer (score 9):

Looks like your editor saved the file in utf-8. Try changing the latin9 parameter to utf8.

Answer (score 4):

For languages other than English you can choose a semiautomatic input selection. For German replace the [inputenc](http://ctan.org/pkg/inputenc) package with these lines.

```
\usepackage{selinput}
\SelectInputMappings{
  adieresis={ä},
  germandbls={ß},
  Euro={€}
}
```

The [selinput](http://ctan.org/pkg/selinput) package is part of the [oberdiek](http://ctan.org/pkg/oberdiek) bundle. It will select the right input encoding in dependence of the file encoding.