# avilable XeTeX editors

Tags: xetex, editors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides)

Can anybody please list Unicode compatible XeTeX editors for Windows which support RTL languages? (I know TeXmaker and Texnic 2alpha )

**Update**:

Lastly I found **TeXstudio**, best RTL (and probably LTR) editor available.

Comment: You should start with [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/5764).

Comment: @Werner I read that page, did not point to XeTeX at all.

Comment: @Reza What you will find in Werner's link is mention of whether editors support UTF-8 input. That's what is key here, as the same considerations apply for LuaTeX users.

Comment: @Reza: There is no XeTeX specific editor to point to. All Unicode capable editors in the topic Werner referred to are for use with XeTeX.

Comment: I added some information about bidi support to the list (for the editors that I could easily test).

Comment: @Donig But I thing most of them do not have "XeLaTeX -> PDF" option by default and most of them are just suitable for Latin script papers and not suitable for Arabic script papers.

Comment: @Reza: TeXnicCenter has support for "XeLaTeX => PDF" - you just need to create the output profile accordingly (to use the correct compiler). Regarding your part two of your comment: Sure, it may be that most editors provide a LTR interface. That said, I think you should visit the websites posted for each of the editors and see whether provide information on RTL support. Do so by visiting the appropriate editor-specific forum(s) (if they exist).

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14876/editors-supporting-unicode