# XeLaTeX, fontspec, Arial (TTF), umlauts?

Tags: xetex, luatex, input-encodings

How do I get german umlauts in a PDF using Arial TT-Font and XeLaTeX or luaLaTeX?

The following example produces a box instead of "ü":

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\begin{document}
\section{Einführung}
Text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use `inputenc` with xelatex.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/frequently-loaded-packages-differences-between-pdflatex-and-xelatex

Comment: Why the downvote? Please explain!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should take a look at the output (log) of XeTeX/LuaTeX:

```
(/opt/texlive2011/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xunicode/xunicode.sty
*** you should *not* be loading the inputenc package
*** XeTeX expects the source to be in UTF8 encoding
*** some features of other encodings may conflict, resulting in poor output.
```

If you follow that advice, the output of your code is correct.

Comment: I saw this before and I also tried without but it didn't help. I have ascii not unicode source files. So there is no chance to get umlauts?

Comment: @AlexG you can still use the `\"a` commands or if you load `babel` you can use the shorthand `"a` for `ä`. With pure ascii, you couldn't key in any umlaut directly (ascii does not define them). You probably have latin1 or any other 8 bit encoding. You can try the package `luainputenc` although I strongly, strongly, strongly and strongly advice against it. (But then I actually ask myself why you have the `utf8` parameter for the `inputenc` package.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I used `latin1` at first, tried `utf8` then (which made it into my question), because the former didn't work out neither with `xelatex` nor with `lualatex`. Both seem to require utf8 encoded source files (unlike pdflatex for example). Thus `luainputenc` seems to be the last resort as I don't want to change my OS to using unicode. What is wrong with luainputenc?

Comment: @AlexG `luainputenc` is really only a last resort. I am not sure if it works in all cases.

Comment: Does anything speak against [changing the encoding of your source files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19427/how-do-i-change-the-encoding-of-my-files)?

Comment: @matth: If I send a utf8 encoded template source file to some person using texniccenter on windows, will further edits in texniccenter (tacitly) keep utf8 encoding?

Comment: Unfortunately, Texniccenter 1 is one of the very few remaining editors that do NOT support UTF8. The [upcoming version 2](http://www.texniccenter.org/news) of TXC will support UTF8. I know some people who use the Alpha 4 productively. In order to make full use of XeLaTeX, you shoud use an [editor that supports UTF8](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14876/editors-supporting-unicode).

Comment: I believe that texniccenter does not use UTF-8, so you probably have to use "a for Umlaut encoding or use `luainputenc` with `latin1`.

Comment: I think I am sufficiently briefed now to continue. Thanks @PatrickGundlach and @matth!

Comment: @AlexG You might consider answering your own question (and accept it) so that future visitors to the site see the solution that worked for you quickly.