# siunitx: µ doesn't work

Tags: symbols, siunitx, greek, units

I'm using TeXnicCenter for Windows (7) and I'm a bloody beginner in everything that concerns LaTeX. I'm using the `siunitx` package for mathematical formulas and it works just fine... with one exception. The `\micro` (e.g. `\si{\micro}`) command doesn't work! It simply doesn't show the `µ` in the PDF file. I've tried to use `\u` as well without success. Does anybody know what the error could be?

Comment: `\micro` is not a unit (it is a quantifier), it is hardly ever written on its own. Have you tried `\si{\micro\metre}`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: @daleif Sounds like an answer to me ...

Comment: @Chris: As daleif has already said, `\micro` is a prefix and will print 'µ', while something like `\micro\metre` is a prefixed unit and will print 'µm'. Your comments on Marco's answer indicate that there is something else up, but without a minimal example it's not really possible to give any more advice.

Comment: PS: Maybe you want to [switch from TXC to TexMaker](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1963/texmaker-and-texniccenter), because TXC 1 does not support UTF-8 (TXC 2 will) but TexMaker does. Plus TexMaker is available for Win, Linux and Mac.

Comment: If you are having trouble with this using XeLaTeX, consider throwing in `\usepackage{unicode-math}`; worked for me where all other solutions did not

Answer (score 43):

I’ll throw this in here, as my search for a solution led me here, but my problem was another one.

Using XeTeX and Latin Modern, I found that the greek letter μ does not work.
However, the Unicode micro sign μ does work.

Knowing that, I added `\sisetup{math-micro=\text{µ},text-micro=µ}`, and now all seems well.

To clarify, use

```
µ
MICRO SIGN
Unicode: U+00B5, UTF-8: C2 B5
```

and *not*

```
μ
GREEK SMALL LETTER MU
Unicode: U+03BC, UTF-8: CE BC
```

for great justice.

MWE for my setup (XeTeX on OS X):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{siunitx}
% Note that the sign must be
%  µ
%  MICRO SIGN
%  Unicode: U+00B5, UTF-8: C2 B5
% and \emph{not}
%  μ
%  GREEK SMALL LETTER MU
%  Unicode: U+03BC, UTF-8: CE BC
\sisetup{math-micro=\text{µ},text-micro=µ}

\begin{document}
Now you can \si\micro\ all the things.
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE screenshot]

Comment: Nice one! It would be great if you can provide a 10-20 lines of compilable LaTeX file with this working in action. We usually even put a screenshot of the resulting file to show the effect in action.

Comment: That is what I recommend in the manual :-)

Comment: @JosephWright When I copy the line from the manual, I get the greek letter. In fact, when I copy the one from my own document which is set up to use the micro sign, I *also* get the greek letter! Not sure why, but might be worth pointing out. :)

Comment: @nlogax The document has to work with pdfLaTeX, so I can only use what is available there. I'm expecting people using XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX to use their system character map application to sort this out.

Comment: I am running *beamer* under XeLaTex with UTF-8 coded input files under Windows (MikTeX). Including the `\sisetup{math-micro=\text{µ},text-micro=µ}` in the preamble does not work. For some reason it has to be included after the `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Isn't the fonts setup at begin document, any thus earlier it will not know what `\text{µ}` is. (I do not use XeLaTeX, so this is just a guess).

Comment: Changing the documentclass in nlogax's answer to `beamer` works fine for me.  You should ask a new question, providing a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 16):

Here is a MWE which compiles fine, using the command @daleif suggested

```
\documentclass[a4paper,final]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[]{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[]{siunitx}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}

  Greek letter \textmu{} in normal text.
  Greek letter µ in normal text.
  The unit for viscosity is \si{\micro\pascal}.
  Just the \si{\micro} is not a SI unit but it works anyway.
  Some number with unit \SI{51}{\micro\metre} lorem ipsum.
  A number with unit in a formula $\SI{123}{\micro\metre}$ dolor sit amet.

\end{document}
```

As shown in the example, use `\si` for just units and capital `\SI` for a value-with-unit-combination. 
And if you want a plain µ in the text, you could also try the command `\textmu` which is made available by the package `\usepackage{textcomp}`

Comment: `\si` is for formatting units, `\SI` is for formatting a number-plus-unit combination (a 'quantity').

Answer (score 5):

Depending on which engine and encoding you use, you can just write a literal μ. Or you can typeset it in math mode as a variable `$\mu$`. It depends on what use the μ has in your document.

If it is a quantifier then add the corresponding unit as daleif already pointed out in the comment.

Comment: Thank you all, so the `$\mu$` and the plain µ are both working. The `\si{\micro\metre}` doesn't :( The problem is that the two working methods return a _µ_. Is there a possibility to get a normal µ still?

Comment: If a plain µ yields a slanted *µ*, then it seems that your font simply doesn't have an upright µ. What is the result of `$\mathup\mu$`?

Comment: Again it returns only a _µ_. Is there no way to add an upright µ to my font?

Comment: You don't really want to add a glyph to your font. But nothing prevents you from defining a command that inserts an upright µ from another font.

Comment: Or you can use `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` to automate this. Or see [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document) or [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11539/change-font-in-a-single-paragraph)

Comment: Thanks @Marco! How do i use the `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` in the correct way? I found this in another thread but still don't get the proper result: `\DeclareMathSymbol{a}{\mathalpha}{mymathvariables}{`a}`. When i follow the instructions in your two links things get even worse and part of my text appears in greek although I'm sure i used greek only as the secondary language :(

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is through the use of the "Babel" package + "Lualatex" as follows, this method defines the symbol as a greek letter:
This answer is in accordance with the solution proposed by David Purton:
[Biblatex usage for multiple languages in same citation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504609/biblatex-usage-for-multiple-languages-in-same-citation)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
% Define used languages
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english} % default language
\babelprovide[import=el]{polutonikogreek}
%Define fonts to be used corressponding to each language (Ordinary ttf fonts installed on your system)
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Times New Roman}
\babelfont[polutonikogreek]{rm}[Language=Default]{Palatino Linotype}

\begin{document}

\foreignlanguage{polutonikogreek}{μ} \\
OR\\

\begin{otherlanguage}{polutonikogreek}
μ \\
\end{otherlanguage}

OR\\
%The method below is not preferred as it only uses the font without language definition, also it can be used with babel or polyglyossia package:

\begingroup
   \newfontfamily\myfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Palatino Linotype}
{\myfont μ}
\endgroup
OR\\
\selectlanguage{polutonikogreek}
μ
\end{document}
```