# Strange behavior with using lmodern together with siunitx package

Tags: siunitx, lmodern

I would like to use the `siunitx` package in my document, but when I try to print an angle with the command `\ang{90}`, I've received

90ř

instead of

90°

Gradual reduction of the code, I found that the reason is the use of the package `lmodern`. How can this problem be solved? It seems that this behavior is similar to the description in the question: [siunitx: µ doesn't work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33965/siunitx-%C2%B5-doesnt-work)

MNWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
 Angle is \ang{90} or \(\ang[number-angle-product = \,]{2.67}\)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not surprising: outside of my normal test rig (you are using an 8-bit font with a Unicode engine, based on loading `xltextra`). For that set up, I'd expect `fontspec` to be loaded.

Comment: Load `fontspec` instead of `xltxtra` and remove `lmodern`.

Answer (score 5):

The set up in `siunitx` for fonts tries to cover a range of 'common' cases. Here, with the Unicode engine XeTeX I'm 'expecting' you to use `fontspec` (perhaps with `unicode-math`). If you'd just loaded `lmodern` things would look OK (but see note below), but adding `xltxtra` before `lmodern` has confused the 'guesses' entirely: it's a far-from typical set up. Once you go 'off piste' you do have to set such things yourself: `siunitx` can't predict every possible combination of font choices. (Loading `fontspec`, which `xltxtra` does, uses the OpenType form of Latin Modern so I'm not really sure what you are aiming for!)

In detail, what happens here is that `siunitx` detects `fontspec` so switches the standard definition for the degree symbol to use the Unicode codepoint (decimal 176). When you then load `lmodern` later, this position is no longer the right glyph as the OT1-encoded font you end up with math mode has something different in that slot.

---

Whilst one can load `lmodern` with XeTeX, the font encoding (OT1 or T1) is wrong: some slots are incorrect and will hyphenate badly. You really should consider using `fontspec` here.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by “confusing the guesses”, because `xltxtra` loads `fontspec`. By the way, `lmodern` is agnostic with respect to output encodings.

Comment: @egreg I've refined a bit. `lmodern` isn't encoding-agnostic: it's an 8-bit font so usable with OT1 or T1 but not TU, which is what we have here.

Comment: The `lmodern` package does something encoding related with math, otherwise just sets values for `\rmdefault`, `\sfdefault` and `\ttdefault`. It doesn't set an output encoding.

Comment: @egreg Yes, but the font files themselves are 8-bit and thus not available in TU

Comment: @JosephWright: Try out `\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}` without lmodern. You are not only assuming that fontspec is loaded, you are actually assuming that it resets some math fonts.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer There's no public interface to pick that up (that I know of), plus as I say in the manual `siunitx`does the best it can for some 'common' cases: outside of that people have to do the set up themselves. Here, there's the issue of 8-bit fonts and Unicode engines, which is non-trivial!

Comment: @JosephWright: You could check (after \begin{document}) the meaning of `\mv@normal`. If symoperators is mapped to OT1 (or not mapped to EUx) you could assume an 8bit font.