# siuntx \micro symbol not shown

Tags: miktex, siunitx

When I compile the next code the micro sign doesn't shown:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    \SI{100}{\micro\metre}

    $\SI{100}{\micro\metre}$
\end{document}
```

I also copied and tried to compile the code given in 
 [siunitx: µ doesn't work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33965/siunitx-%C2%B5-doesnt-work) :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{siunitx}

% Note that the sign must be
%  µ
%  MICRO SIGN
%  Unicode: U+00B5, UTF-8: C2 B5
% and \emph{not}
%  μ
%  GREEK SMALL LETTER MU
%  Unicode: U+03BC, UTF-8: CE BC

\sisetup{math-micro=\text{µ},text-micro=µ}

\begin{document}
Now you can \si\micro\ all the things.
\end{document}
```

But I get a `'Fatal Package fontspec Error: fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTex.'`

I am using MikTex2.9.

What can be done??

Comment: Your first example works fine for me. Do you get any warnings in your log file about missing fonts? The second example needs to be compiled with xelatex or lualatex instead of pdflatex.

Comment: I have no issues with either. Are you sure your MikTeX is 100% up to date both as user and admin? I'm currently updating my TeXLive 2019,  to see if there are newer stuff that is problematic, it will take a few minutes. Still no issues after full update.

Comment: The compilation results show 0 warnings, and I also  didn't find warnings in the log file. I downloaded MikTex2.9 last week from the official site.

Comment: How did you look in the log? Actually at the log or the parsed stuff that your editor shows you? Might be an idea to post the log as well as the MWEs. SInce miktex does not use cm-super as default (TeXLive does), does adding the `lmodern` package do anything?

Comment: The package 'lmodern' sloved the problem. Thank you very much !!!!

Comment: Just to debug in case others have this issue. Can you post the log for the original two MWEs **without** the use of `lmodern`. We'd like to know exactly what is going on as we have trouble recreating it.