# Text line alignment issued with TIKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, arabic

Upon trying to make a border around my page using the tikz command, the first line of text after the tikz command is misaligned (Sine the document is in arabic ( Main language setting)) where the text is aligned at the LHS not the RHS. Also words are typed correctly but are in reverse order.
Upon cancelling the border, the text output is correct.
I am USING XELATEX + POLYGLYOSSIA
HERE IS THE LINK FOR THE SIMPLIFIED ARABIC FONT (INSTALL IT ON WINDOWS TO RUN THE CODE CORRECTLY : https://fontzone.net/font-details/simplified-arabic

Here is the CODE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox} 
\usepackage{url,graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,arrows,positioning,matrix,quotes, shapes.geometric,calc}   
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=gregorian,locale=default,numerals=mashriq]{arabic} 
\setotherlanguages{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Mapping=arabicdigits]{Simplified Arabic} 


\title{jhhjjhhj}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{شكر وتقدير} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
         \draw[line width = 4pt] ($(current page.north west) + (1in,-1in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (-1in,1in)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\textbf{
يتقدم المؤلف بالشكر لكل من:}

\end{document}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: On MikTeX (XeLaTeX)  i have these errors: `Package fontspec Error: The font "Simplified Arabic" cannot be found`; and also `! Package fontspec Error: The font "Ezra SIL" cannot be found.` and also with `"FreeSerifAvvaShenouda" cannot be found`, and also with `"Serto Jerusalem" `

Comment: You have to add these fonts to your system, they are *.ttf files, they are the same exact fonts used in MS-office. You can download and install them them to windows.

Comment: Ok. Where can i find these fonts? Do you have an internet link?

Comment: https://fontzone.net/font-details/simplified-arabic

Comment: https://www.cufonfonts.com/font/palatino-linotype

Comment: https://www.wfonts.com/font/ezra-sil

Comment: Please indicate in your question sites that you have tested yourself (virus-free) and that allow you to download and install these fonts.

Comment: http://www.moheb.de/unicode_coptic_fonts.html

Comment: I did DL the fonts from them, I had no issues

Comment: I downloaded the first one and it does not appear when I open the `install` button that normally appears to install a font on Windows 10.

Comment: http://bethmardutho.org/meltho/

Comment: I just installed these last fonts, but the same errors occur.

Comment: The font is not relevant to the question. Just use Amiri, which we all have.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is twofold.

When you run your `tikz` picture straight into the `\textbf{}` the RTL flow of text is messed up.

And if you leave a paragraph space to fix this, then you get unwanted vertical space.

You need to use a method like the one in the `eso-pic` package to add the border into the page background at shipout time.

## MWE

This MWE adds the border to any page that includes the `\insertpageborder` command.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox} 
\usepackage{url,graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,arrows,positioning,matrix,quotes, shapes.geometric,calc}   
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=gregorian,locale=default,numerals=mashriq]{arabic} 
\setotherlanguages{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Mapping=arabicdigits]{Amiri} 

\usepackage{eso-pic}

\newcommand{\insertpageborder}{%
  \AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
      \draw[line width = 4pt] ($(current page.north west) + (1in,-1in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (-1in,1in)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{شكر وتقدير}
\insertpageborder

\textbf{يتقدم المؤلف بالشكر لكل من:}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: How can I determine the location where such border may appear, since I require it at certain locations along the document?

Comment: @Silva, The coordinates you have in your MWE give an offset of 1in from each page corner. You can change these offsets to whatever you want.

Comment: @ David, I mean, the page itself, how can I choose the page, Like in the front matter, before introduction.... On which page, Do I paste the code Where I want it to appear?

Comment: @Silva, If you need it at random locations, you can insert the `\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{…}` to whichever pages you need, rather than patching `\@chapter`. The non-starred version puts it's contents on every page. The starred version on the current page.

Comment: I tried it and did not work, is it possible to amend the code?

Comment: @Silva, I updated my answer.