# Section names and page numbers do not appear correctly

Tags: sectioning, numbering, naming

I used the `fancyhdr` package to change header and footer style. I made it so that chapter names appear in header. Also, I set it so that the chapter number appears before the page number in footers. I am using XELATEX + POLYGLOSSIA

- Regarding page numbering: it does not appear in the table of contents as it does in the footer, only the page number without chapter number appear.
- Regarding chapter names: the labels of Chapter naming do not appear correctly in the header (they differ from the header and main chapter name).
  (LINK FOR ARABIC FONT (DL and INSTALL) https://fontzone.net/font-details/simplified-arabic)
  This modification appears correctly in the header:

```
\gappto\captionsarabic{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{الباب}}
```

while this one does not:

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\thechapter}{\words{chapter}}{}{}          
\makeatother
```

Here is the full code:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage [hidelinks,colorlinks=true,linkcolor = blue,anchorcolor = blue,citecolor = blue,filecolor = blue,urlcolor = blue]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{url,graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,arrows,positioning,matrix,quotes, shapes.geometric,calc}  
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\rightmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}
\cfoot{\thechapter-\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2pt}
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=gregorian,locale=default,numerals=mashriq]{arabic} 
\setotherlanguages{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Mapping=arabicdigits]{Simplified Arabic} 
% MACROS FOR CHANGING CHAPTER NAMES %
\gappto\captionsarabic{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{الباب}} %to name the chapter title   الباب instead of باب   
    \newcommand\words[1]{\expandafter\xwords\csname c@#1\endcsname}
    \def\xwords#1{\ifcase#1\or
    الأول\or
    الثاني\or
    الثالث\or
    الرابع\or
    الخامس\or
    السادس\or
    السابع\or
    الثامن\or
    التاسع\or
    العاشر\or
الحادي عشر\or 
الثاني عشر\or 
الثالث عشر\or 
الرابع عشر\or 
الخامس عشر\or 
السادس عشر\or  
السابع عشر\or
الثامن عشر\or 
التاسع عشر\or 
العشرون\or 
    \else
    I need more words أحتاج إلى المزيد من ترقيمات الأبواب بالحروف في ملف arbbook.cls\fi}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}  
    \makeatletter
    \patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\thechapter}{\words{chapter}}{}{}          
    \makeatother
% 
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents{}


\chapter{fgfdfgfdg}

\subsection{سيسس}

\subsection{سيسس}

\subsection{سيسس}

\subsection{سيسس}

\newpage

\subsection{سيسس}

\subsection{سيسس}

\subsection{سيسس}

\subsection{سيسس}

\end{document}
```

[image: TABLE OF CONTENTS]
[image: Chapter NAme]
[image: Page Numbering]

Comment: Hi, I might have been able to answer some of your questions, but every time, I stumble on the fact that I can't compile your sample documents. For instance, here, I don't know which engine you are using. I try LuaTeX and get `Undefined control sequence` for `\luatexpardir`. After some Googling, I add `\directlua{tex.enableprimitives("luatex",tex.extraprimitives("luatex"))}` to the preamble and recompile (maybe this is a bad idea); I then get `Package fontspec Error: The font "SimplifiedArabic" cannot be found`. The font in question doesn't appear to be in my distro, so I give up.

Comment: All this to say that *if* your problems are not directly related to the arabic language, you could probably obtain more help by submitting your code samples with an English setup (including English-only sample text). Of course, this doesn't help for questions related to arabic language and/or right-to-left typesetting. This is not a criticism, I'm just trying to help you get more answers if this is possible.

Comment: I am using XELATEX ti compile, THe arabic font can be installed on windows normally, HERE IS THE LINK: https://www.wfonts.com/font/simplified-arabic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although, your question is not quite clear to me (probably because I can't read Arabic), I think this does what you want. I've made use of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/505045/87678). You're probably going to have to spend some time reading through the `babel` manual to understand all its BiDi settings and options to get the output you want I think.

## MWE

Compile with `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic-r,layout=counters]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}
\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Amiri}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2pt}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\thechapter-\csname @arabic\endcsname\c@page}
\makeatother

\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\gappto\captionsarabic{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{الباب}}

\newcommand\words[1]{\expandafter\xwords\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\xwords#1{%
  \ifcase#1\or
  الأول\or
  الثاني\or
  الثالث\or
  الرابع\or
  \else
  I need more words\fi}    
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\Hy@org@chapter}
  {\begingroup \renewcommand{\thechapter}{{\words{chapter}}}}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\Hy@org@chapter}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\@chapapp\space\words{chapter}\space#1}}
  {}
  {}
\apptocmd{\Hy@org@chapter}
  {\endgroup}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}
  {\thechapter}
  {\words{chapter}}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{}

\chapter{سيسس}

\section{سيسس}

\subsection{سيسس}

\subsection{سيسس}

\subsection{سيسس}

\clearpage

\section{سيسس}

\subsection{سيسس}

\subsection{سيسس}

\subsection{سيسس}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The page numbering in the table of contents is fixed, however, the word "Chapter" in the titles in table of contents disappeared. Also, The spacing between the words has disappeared. So if if should appear as "Chapter One Title" it appears as "OneTitle" WHere the word chapter is omitted and the spacing between the chapter numbering and chapter title is omitted making them appear as one word

Comment: @Silva, sorry I struggle because I can't read Arabic at all :(

Comment: no worries, if it is a bit too much, upon adding an appendix, appendix numbering is set to 1,2,3 ..... rather than A1, A2...... Can this be related to any of the mods related page numbering?? Notice that I am using the subfiles package where each chapter is in a separate file

Comment: @Silva Does my latest edit show the chapter like you want in the TOC?

Comment: @Silva, I think I need a clearer question for your appendix issue. Maybe start from the MWE in this answer and add `\appendix` in front of a second `\chapter` and ask a new question explaining the output you want.

Comment: latest edit solved the issue. ThX

Comment: @ david: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505804/page-numbering-for-different-sections