# problem with polyglossia and hyperref

Tags: xetex, hyperref, polyglossia

Here a minimal example, I don't know where is the problem?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,
    urlcolor=cyan,
    citecolor=blue
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1,AutoFakeSlant=-0.03]{Amiri}
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Amiri}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@chapter}{\begingroup \renewcommand{\thechapter}{{\words{chapter}}}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\@chapter}{\endgroup}{}{}
\makeatother




%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  MACRO FOR LITERAL NUMBERING %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\words[1]{\expandafter\xwords\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\xwords#1{\ifcase#1\or
الأول\or
الثاني\or
الثالث\or
الرابع\or
\else
I need more words\fi}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\thechapter}{\words{chapter}}{}{}
\makeatother





%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% REDEFINES \THECHAPTER IN CONTENTS
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@chapter}{\begingroup \renewcommand{\thechapter}{{\words{chapter}}}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\@chapter}{\endgroup}{}{}
\makeatother


\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
\ChNumVar{\Large}% Dimension of the number of the chapter in the first page... instead of the default...\ChNumVar{\Huge}


\begin{document}

\chapter{واحد}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would say you are out of luck. fncychap wants to be after bidi/polyglossia to redefine the look of a chapter, hyperref wants to be after fncychap to insert the destination code in a chapter, and bidi wants to be behind hyperref for whatever reason. A nice circle.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer in any place I put them there is an error

Comment: yes, as I wrote: A circle.

Comment: there is no solutions ?@UlrikeFischer

Comment: Could you switch to LuaLaTeX and `babel` instead of XeLaTeX and `polyglossia`? Then you don't have to use `bidi`.

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not be a suitable answer, but as far as I can see (as someone who can't understand Arabic) it gives the same output as your MWE without `hyperref` (including in the TOC and headers).

I've switched to using `babel` and LuaLaTeX to get around the load order problems with `bidi`. And patched `\Hy@org@chapter`. This is the original `\@chapter` macro which `hyperref` embeds into its own new `\@chapter`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic-r]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import]{english}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}[Scale=1.1, AutoFakeSlant=-0.03]{Amiri}
\babelfont[arabic]{sf}[Scale=1.1]{Amiri}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
\ChNumVar{\Large}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  filecolor=magenta,
  urlcolor=cyan,
  citecolor=blue
}
\newcommand\words[1]{\expandafter\xwords\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\xwords#1{%
  \ifcase#1\or
  الأول\or
  الثاني\or
  الثالث\or
  الرابع\or
  \else
  I need more words\fi}    
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\Hy@org@chapter}
  {\begingroup \renewcommand{\thechapter}{{\words{chapter}}}}
  {}
  {}
\apptocmd{\Hy@org@chapter}
  {\endgroup}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}
  {\thechapter}
  {\words{chapter}}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother    
\begin{document}    
\chapter{واحد}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: but I want to use "Amiri" to write , is there something to replace Hyperref?

Comment: @PolineSandra, you can use any font you want

Comment: @PolineSandra, I don't really understand you comment actually. My MWE does use Amiri and `hyperref`. There is no other package that does the same as `hyperref`.

Comment: I don't see it I'm sorry @David Purton

Comment: @PolineSandra the `\babelfont` lines set the font to Amiri. Did you try to compile my example? What happens?