# How to double-click in PDF document to go to source code?

Tags: pdf, viewers, forward-inverse-search

When creating a document, I usually build a DVI document because the YAP viewer has a nice feature which allows me to double-click on a word in the DVI document which then causes the source-code window to appear with the cursor on the word (or line) in the source code corresponding to the word in the DVI document where I clicked.  My understanding is that this feature is not available with PDF documents?  Is this correct or can I set up a PDF viewer to cross-reference the source code when I click a word in the PDF document?

Comment: *Forward- and backward search* are the required buzzwords. I recommend [Sumatra PDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html) for Windows which can automatically make some adjustments for WinEdt and TexnicCenter.

Comment: You can set this up with a PDF viewer, with SyncTeX. It is for example enabled by default in TeXworks, where you Ctrl + click to move between preview and source. Which editor do you use?

Comment: The easiest way would be to use [Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/index.html) or TeXworks. TeXworks is included in MikTex as well as TexLive. Both support forward and inverse search via synctex out of the box. But if you are used to TXC then you will probably like the interface of Texmaker better. For a comparison of TXC and Texmaker read this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1963/texmaker-and-texniccenter

Comment: There appears to be a more authoritative answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116981/how-to-configure-texniccenter-2-0-with-sumatra-2013-version