# How to configure TeXnicCenter 2.0 with Sumatra (2013--2016 version)

Tags: pdf, viewers, texniccenter, forward-inverse-search, sumatrapdf

Despite having gone through

[Configure TexnicCenter with something else than Adobe Reader X](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12500/configure-texniccenter-with-something-else-than-adobe-reader-x/12531#12531)

and having looked at the [TeXnicCenter + Sumatra Tutorial](http://sourceforge.net/projects/texniccenter/files/Tutorials/How_to_Sumatra_EN_%282010.03.07%29.pdf/download), there seems to some little changes for TeXnicCenter version 2.0 as of May 2013.  How can I make TeXnicCenter 2.0 to work with Sumatra?

Comment: Can you add a real question?

Comment: @karlkoeller I don't have a question, I simply used the *answer your own question* option, because I recently came up with this issue.  Unfortunately, the answers contained in the site are outdated.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that to _answer your own question_ one would have to post the question and **then** to post an answer. But I'm quite new here...

Comment: @karlkoeller you are right, Mario wrote only the question and no answer. Mario can you please add an answer and change the question? Or to left a comment behind that questions showing wrong informations?

Comment: Please skip to StackJack 's comment of Aug 23rd '18 below the accepted answer

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Follow all the steps mentioned in the  [TeXnicCenter + Sumatra Tutorial](http://sourceforge.net/projects/texniccenter/files/Tutorials/How_to_Sumatra_EN_%282010.03.07%29.pdf/download), but keep in mind these few things:

1. In the *(La)TeX* tab / *(La)TeX compiler* section / *Command line arguments to pass to the compiler* bar, you should write: `-synctex=-1 -interaction=nonstopmode "%Wm"`
2. In the *Viewer* tab / *Executable path* section, what should be written is: `"C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" -inverse-search "\"C:\Program Files\TeXnicCenter\TeXnicCenter.exe\" /ddecmd \"[goto('%f','%l')]\""`.  Please note:

   1.1 What should be written is a complete line, with spaces between line breakings (it just doesn't fit entirely here to show).

   1.1.1 The path could be different in your computer (e.g., your path for the executable file could be in `"C:\Program Files (x86)\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe"`) or depending on your system's language could be something like `C:\Programme\...`

   1.2 If you copy + paste from Adobe Reader from the tutorial, it is not going to work, as it seems to copy the `'` as ` instead.

   1.3 The new executable file for TeXnicCenter 2.0 is actually named `TeXnicCenter.exe`, not `TEXCNTR.EXE`, as it appears in the tutorial.
3. In the *Viewer* tab / *View project's output* section, you should select `DDE command` and the command should be `"%bm.pdf"` (as described in the tutorial) and the server should be `SUMATRA`. The *topic* should be `control`
4. In the *Viewer* tab / *Forward search* section, you should select `DDE command` and the command should be `[ForwardSearch("%bm.pdf","%Wc",%l,0,0,1)]` (as described in the tutorial) and the server should be `SUMATRA`. The *topic* should be `control`
5. In the *Viewer* tab / *Close document before running (La)TeX* section you should select `Do not close`.

Graphical Description:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to add graphics to text and mention what has mainly changed with respect to configuring `TeXnicCenter 2 Beta 1` and [`Sumatra pdf 2.3.2`](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/news.html) compared to earlier sumatra versions in either Q or A to be more user friendly/catchy ?

Comment: thanks a lot for note 1.2!!! I was searching this mistake for quite some time...

Comment: You're welcome @user33135, and [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: @user33135: You can also give feedback by replying “Yes” to the question “Was this post useful to you?”. You’ll find this question under every post. Once you’ve gathered 15 reputation points on this site, you’ll be able to upvote answers

Comment: For me this is working well, thank you, but ONE thing still annoys me: The viewer sumatra doesn't popup to the front (foreground), so I always have to select it. And about the inverse search: Is that normal that by double clicking the cursor does **NOT** automatically skip to the double-clicked **word** but only to the paragraph/sentence/item??

Comment: @bjoern It is normal that when you do double click on a *word* in the Sumatra pdf you'll get directed to the *paragraph* in TeXnicCenter.  Regarding the popup, it works perfectly with me (Windows Vista + TeXnicCenter 2.02 + Sumatra 2.3.2)

Comment: Tried different things but cant get it to work to always get to the front... I even tried to use a DDE command to close sumatra before compiling thus always reopening because upon reopening, it comes to the front focus. But the close command didn't work either..

Comment: As an additional comment, always check the full path of Sumatra and of TeXnicCenter using the command prompt.  I was confused by a Windows in Italian, where these programs appears under "Programmi" but are in reality under "Program Files"

Comment: I had to restart TeXnicCenter to get this change to work.

Comment: This explanation nearly worked for me on TexnicCentre 2.02 on Windows. I had to remove the " at the beginning and end of the Executable path. These " are shown in the graphical description. Has anyone else been able to get this suggestion to work when including the "? I found it would work if I had already loaded up sumatra. Should the Executable path be changed in the answer?

Comment: @Chogg No, the answer is just fine.  Those `"` are there so the system knows where to find the pdf reader.  I also have TeXnicCenter 2.02 and my complete entry (including path) is `"C:\Program Files (x86)\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" -inverse-search "\"C:\Program Files\TeXnicCenter\TeXnicCenter.exe\" /ddecmd \"[goto('%f','%l')]\""`

Comment: On the [news site of WinEdt](http://www.winedt.com/news.html) it is stated that 
'PDF macros no longer use DDE for SumatraPDF. Using the command line switch -forward-search is faster and more reliable. Using a command line switch (if it exists) is always preferable (simple is better). Besides DDE does not (and will not) support Unicode!'

Is this also true for TeXnicCenter? If so, an example how to set up the viewer settings using command line instead of DDE would be very much appreciated.

Comment: @StackJack Your wish is my command line :-) see [CLI answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453670/adobe-reader-makes-texniccenter-crash-alternative-sumatra)

Answer (score 5):

One further point to consider is the the language of the OS you're using. As I had to learn two different names in links (`C:\Programme\...` *vs* `C:\Program Files\...` which point to the same directory for a German Win 7 OS and are mapped by the OS automatically) are two different directories for the DDE. While the forward search was working as intended, the inverse search always fired up a new instance which lead to a project already in use clash.

After fixing this issue, everything works fine :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: It does not work here. The paths are correct, so are the various brackets and quotes. When I double click in Sumatra, nothing happens.