# open pdf at current page using TeXnicCenter and Adobe Reader, or should I use another setup?

Tags: hyperref, pdf, viewers, texniccenter, adobe

Is it nowadays possible to open the compiled pdf at that position, where the last change happend, using the aforementioned TeXnicCenter and Adobe Reader?

I used my favourite search engine ;) but didn't found anything, except some threads from 2011 where they stated, that it would not be possible.

But then I found, that the `hyperref` package has a setting `\hypersetup{...}` with `pdfstartpage` but I didn't get it to work.

If the anwser is still: "It's not possible!", my next question would be: which setup/programs should I use, so that it is possible? Or isn't it possible in general?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If I'm on a Windows machine I use `sumatra` while I'm constructing the document, and once it is complete if I need to print it, I'll do so from `adobe`. See [How to configure TeXnicCenter 2.0 with Sumatra (2013 version)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116981) and the links within for details

Answer (score 2):

The `hyperref` Package is only for the "after-compile-use". The feature you are searching for is `forward search`.
As far as I know `forward search` is not possible with Adobe Reader.
I am using [SumatraPDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/download-free-pdf-viewer.html) with TeXnicCenter. Forward and inverse search is working.

At a pdf outputting profile, use this settings:

Insert `-synctex=1` in the commandline of the compiler. ((La)TeX tab)

Open with SumatraPDF DDEcommand: (viewer tab)

```
[Open("%bm.pdf",0,1,1)]
```

Server: `SUMATRA` Topic: `Control`

Forward Search with DDE command (in the viewer tab):

```
[ForwardSearch("%bm.pdf","%Wc",%l,0,0,1)]
```

Server: `SUMATRA` Topic: `Control`

Inverse Search with Sumatra: (modify at "path of executable" in viewer tab)

```
"Path to SumatraPDF" -inverse-search "\"Path to TeXnicCenter\" /ddecmd \"[goto('%f', '%l')]\""
```

And choose do not close at the viewer tab.

The forward and inverse search only works with PDF or DVI output. For DVI you have to modify the DVI-output-profile with an forward-inverse-search-compatible DVI-viewer. (for Example YAP)

For another excellent explantaion for the use of SumatraPDF and TeXnicCenter look at [this Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116981/36879) and [Willam Blums site](http://william.famille-blum.org/blog/static.php?page=static081010-000413)