# TXC compiles document and opens PDF and hangs

Tags: texniccenter

Editor : TXC 2.0 b2
sumatra 2.3.2

I can compile the document without any errors. but after compilation, the TXC opens the sumatra and gets stuck. I have to force terminate the programs.

But the PDF file generated is correct and found in the folder. I just am not able to do build and view it in sumatra.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\title{Introduction to \LaTeX{}}
\author{Author's Name}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
The abstract text goes here.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
Here is the text of your introduction.

\begin{equation}
\label{simple_equation}
\alpha = \sqrt{ \beta }
\end{equation}

\subsection{Subsection Heading Here}
Write your subsection text here.


\section{Conclusion}
Write your conclusion here.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have a script running matlab by any chance? :) This often happens when CPU is super busy (at least that's when it happens to me)

Comment: @percusse No. Infact the only thing that is running is TXC. Even otherwise does this happen because the CPU is busy ?

Comment: What about with other PDF viewers?

Comment: Restart your computer and try again. If the output (PDF) is successfully created, I don't think this is related to TeXnicCenter.

Comment: I have a guess that this is related to handling SyncTeX process and yes when the CPU is busy it hangs after Sumatra opens but before the pdf file opens and jumps to the correct page.

Comment: Are you sure you have configured it in the correct way? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116981/how-to-configure-texniccenter-2-0-with-sumatra-2013-version

Comment: I had all the configurations correct. But guess what, I just updated the Miktex repository and voila started working again.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was solved with a software update.