# Configure TeXnic Center with Sumatra

Tags: texniccenter, sumatrapdf

so I've been trying for a while to configure those two programs, but I just can't get it to work. I always get the error: [ForwardSearch("%bm.pdf","%Wc",%l,0,0,...  Cannot execute the command.

My settings are:
 [image: The following are my settings.]

Comment: Please add the full command you are using (the executable path)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116981/how-to-configure-texniccenter-2-0-with-sumatra-2013-version

Comment: @papabravo this is the executable path:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" -inverse-search "\"C:\Programme (x86)\TeXnicCenter\TeXnicCenter.exe\" /ddecmd \"[goto('%f','%l')]\""

Comment: @MarioS.E. yes that's what I used, I have no idea where I went wrong..

Comment: Have you tried to use `C:\Program Files (x86)\TeXnicCenter\...` instead of the the German version?

Answer (score 3):

This configuration works for me.

**Executable path**

`C:\Program Files (x86)\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe -inverse-search "\"C:\Program Files\TeXnicCenter\TeXnicCenter\TeXnicCenter.exe\" /ddecmd \"[goto('%f','%l')]\""`

**View project's output**

DDE command

Command:"%bm.pdf"

Server: SUMATRA

Topic: control

**Forward Search**

DDE command

Command:[ForwardSearch("%bm.pdf","%Wc",%l,0,0,1)]

Server: SUMATRA

Topic: control

**Close document before running (La)TeX**

Do not close

[image]

Comment: It does not work for me. After TeXnicCenter opens Sumatra, if I double click on a word, Sumatra displays the error "Cannot start inverse search command. Please check the command line in the settings".