# "Cannot Execute the Command" error with sumatraPDF in TeXnicCenter

Tags: errors, texniccenter

When I build the output, I can view it in pdf using `sumatrapdf` by pressing F5 sometimes, but most of the time I have to rebuild the output until it works.  The error is:

[image]

When I build the pdf, I can open the pdf using `SumatraPDF` by going to the folder and opening it, but I would prefer to be able to do it by pressing F5.

I am using the  following settings:

[image]

[image]

There are some lines that run past the picture; here they are:

Command line arguments to pass to the compiler:

```
-synctex=-1 -max-print-line=120 -interaction=nonstopmode "%wm"
```

Executable path (Viewer tab, first line)

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe -inverse-search "\"C:\Program Files\TeXnicCenter\TeXnicCenter\TeXnicCenter.exe\" /ddecmd \"[goto('%f','%l')]\""
```

(These are the same settings (including file paths, which I think are correct because that is where I find the executables in the folders) as in [Configure TeXnic Center with Sumatra](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140326/configure-texnic-center-with-sumatra) for the viewer tab and the same settings as suggested in [How to configure TeXnicCenter 2.0 with Sumatra (2013--2016 version)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116981/how-to-configure-texniccenter-2-0-with-sumatra-2013-2016-version) for the (La)TeX tab)

What can I do to fix this, or is there any more information I should provide?

Comment: I assume you're fine with an updated view in SumatraPDF until some random later compilation. Correct? The only way around this I've found is to restart TeXnicCentre. There is a similar issue with Adobe Reader (before I switched)... it may be an issue with the editor.

Comment: Related: [TeXnicCenter - Forward search issue](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112463/5764)

Comment: Related: [ForwardSearch: “Cannot execute the command” when using LuaLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/144500/5764) (I don't think it's an issue with LuaLaTeX)

Comment: @Werner can you clarify what you mean by "an updated view in SumatraPDF"?

Comment: Related: [Configure TeXnic Center with Sumatra](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140326/5764)

Comment: SumatraPDF updates without problem when you compile... but after a number of compilation the error shows?

Comment: @Werner The error sometimes (read: often) shows if I try to use SumatraPDF through TeXnicCenter, but if I open the pdf file with SumatraPDF not through TeXnicCenter it's fine.  As it turns out, I don't actually have to go to the folder with the pdf and reopen it; when I build, SumatraPDF updates it automatically.  Restarting TeXnicCenter does not guarantee that the error will not show the first time.

Comment: Yes, SumatraPDF as a viewer is fine; the issue is related to an interaction between TeXnicCenter and SumatraPDF. Since I've experienced similar errors with a different viewer (Adobe Reader), I'm thinking this might be related to TeXnicCenter. However, one would need specific information on how to replicate the problem, which is difficult to do but necessary, and then report it to the [TXC bug list](https://sourceforge.net/p/texniccenter/bugs/).

Comment: I have been having this same exact issue since last week (suddenly). It's very annoying. My issue is not intermittent though, it's EVERY TIME (which is at least easier to replicate, I guess). Maybe it needs to go to the TXC bug list. Restarting both TeXnicCenter and SumatraPDF seems to have solved the issue for me (at least for now).

Comment: DDE calling sumatraPDF is depreciated as are many other OLD "fixes" please follow https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453670/adobe-reader-makes-texniccenter-crash-alternative-sumatra/453731?r=SearchResults&s=1|0.0000#453731

Answer (score 2):

In your third image you showed that your configuration is missing something. The command for the "view project's outputs" has to be:

```
[DocOpen("%bm.pdf")][FileOpen("%bm.pdf")]
```

Please see the following image from my profile (in german, but you can see easily where you have to change it ...):

[image]

Comment: I did as you indicated but it did not work for me :(

Comment: It did not work in my case too. The issue remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

After having the same problem and finding this post, my issues were eventually solved by the solution posted here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199646, i.e. adding the command **--synctex=1** in the (La)Tex Command line arguments to pass to the compiler.

Comment: Nothing changed in my case. Everytime I update something, I have to solve this issue here again and again.

Comment: Please use the method described here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453670/adobe-reader-makes-texniccenter-crash-alternative-sumatra/453731?r=SearchResults&s=1|0.0000#453731