# ForwardSearch: "Cannot execute the command" when using LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, texniccenter, forward-inverse-search, adobe, sumatrapdf

If I try to compile with the LuaLaTeX-compiler in TeXnicCenter with the below outputprofile-settings, there showing up this error:
`[ForwardSearch("%bm.pdf","%Wc",%l,0,0,1)] Cannot execute the command`

It seems, that my viewer doesn't accept the command for forward search.

I have just run the wizzard for ouputprofiles. This has configured the settings in the "LuaLaTeX->pdf" profile as follows:

**(La)Tex-Tab**

1. Path to compiler: `C:\Program Files\Miktex\miktex\bin\x64\lualatex.exe`
2. Command line arguments: `-synctex=-1 -interaction=nonstopmode "%wm"`

**Viewer-Tab**

1. Executable path: 
       `C:\Program Files (x86)\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe -inverse-search "\"C:\Program Files\TeXnicCenter\TeXnicCenter.exe\" /ddecmd \"[goto('%f','%l')]\""`
2. View projects's output
    
       Command line Argument
       
       Command: `"%bm.pdf"`

   Forwardsearch
     
   DDE command
      
   Command: `[ForwardSearch("%bm.pdf","%Wc",%l,0,0,1)]`
      
   Server: `sumatra`
      
   Topic: `control`

   Close document before running
        
       Do not close

The problem exist only for the "LuaLaTeX->pdf" profile. The "Latex->pdf" still keeps working good.

Maybe there is an lualatex- and texniccenteruser outhere, who can have look in his settings for a comparison with my settings?

I use:

- Texniccenter 2.02 Stable (64 bit)
- SumatraPDF v2.4

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) This error is only about opening a file. Was it created in the folder?! Is the executable path for your viewer is OK at `Build/Define output profile/LuaLaTeX->pdf/viewer`?

Comment: What do you mean with: Was it created in the folder? I simply try to compile a created minimal helloworldprojekt. I think the viewerpath is OK. Like I said, with normal latex-code and normal latex-compiler every thing works fine. If I try to compile with preset "LuaLateX->pdf" profile or if I try to make a new Profile, like described above, I get the described error. Does anybody know how to compile lualatex with TeXnicCenter?

Comment: After the installation of »Sumatra PDF« you can try to rebuild the profiles by pressing "Alt+F7" and starting the wizard. TXC2 prefers Sumatra over the AR and does the correct settings. I don't have any problems with the default settings.

Comment: I have followed your instruction. You can see the result in the edit above.

Comment: Try `[ForwardSearch("%bm.pdf","%Wc",%l,0,0,0)]` in the `command` box of the `viewer` tab

Comment: I had the exact same issue. Refer the link given by Mario S.E and note that it's best to type out the commands yourself. I wasted a whole one hour and it turned out to be a problem with one double-quote which was a pasted one from some blog. I typed it out and bingo! things were working nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx for all answering, but none of the answers solves the problem. Just the following procedure brings a solution: Deinstalled Sumatra, Texniccenter and Miktex. Removed the folders from Sumatra and Miktex in 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming'. Running Piriform-Registrycleaner. Running Wise-Registrycleaner. Installed first Miktex to an other direction as before. Then installed Sumatra and after this Texniccenter (note the order of installing the programms!).

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem. In addition, I saw that lualatex does not produce a synctex.gz file. therefore, the forward search commando can not be executed.

I was able to solve the problem, by changing the Option "Command line arguments to pass to the compiler" (On the tab *(La)Tex* of the profile) to

**-interaction=nonstopmode  --synctex=1 "%Wm"**

especially, note the additional - before synctex.

Afterwards, forward search works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using TeXnicCenter and I have no problem with this config on the `viewer` tab, as described in [How to configure TeXnicCenter 2.0 with Sumatra (2013--2016 version)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116981/how-to-configure-texniccenter-2-0-with-sumatra-2013-version) ---the rest of the settings are just like yours:

**View projects's output**

DDE command

Command: "%bm.pdf"

server: SUMATRA

Topic: Control

---

**Forward Search**

DDE command

command: [ForwardSearch("%bm.pdf","%Wc",%l,0,0,0)]

server: SUMATRA

Topic: control

---