# Kile and LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, kile

After failing to compile some lualatex-code in texniccenter (see here: [ForwardSearch: "Cannot execute the command" when using LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144500/lualatex-texniccenter-adobexi-and-sumatra)), I would like to compile a minimale example in kile.

Where I can find the settings to compile with lualatex in kile?

Comment: Do you mean Setting -> Build -> LuaLaTeX?

Answer (score 5):

At least on my system, there is no default option to do this. However, it is not difficult to create such an option.

Settings > Configure Kile [should get you the configuration window. This option might be somewhere else on other systems - I'm not sure.]

Once in the configuration screen, choose

Tools > Build from the list.

Underneath the list of tools, click the "New" button. Enter the name you want to use e.g. LuaLaTeX and click next. It will ask you what to base the configuration on. Pick something similar e.g. XeLaTeX or PDFLaTeX. Click finish.

Now you need to edit the options by filling in the command name and the options you want to pass to it. The easiest way is to copy something from one of the other tool's options and then just adjust it as necessary. Probably you want "lualatex" for the command, for example, and something like "-interaction=nonstopmode '%source'" for options.

When you are satisfied, save your changes. You should get a new compile option in the build menu corresponding to your new settings.

Note that this is a lot easier to do than it is to describe and will be a lot faster to do, as well!