# How to configure Kile to run arara

Tags: compiling, kile, arara

I'm working under Ubuntu and I have  `TeX Live 2015` installed. I need to know if it is possible to use `arara` with `Kile`, how to add a menu entry for it and finally how to run `arara` on projects.

Comment: Related (basic principle is identical for setting up a new build in Kile): [Kile and LuaLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145669) and [Configure kile and biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20328)

Comment: I use Arara with Kile. Pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is pretty straightforward. For example, here are the settings I use:

[image: tab 1]

[image: tab 2]

[image: tab 3]

Then just configure a short cut of your choice, if desired.

Running Arara on a project is just like compiling any other project in Kile. If your file is part of a project and you've set the project up with a root document, then running Arara will compile the root document even if that is not the current file. (Whether this is what you want or not is, obviously, rather context dependent.)