# Sync between Adobe and Texniccenter

Tags: texniccenter, forward-inverse-search, adobe

I am using TeXnicCenter and Adobe Acrobat Pro 11. My problem is whenever I compile my article in TeX -> PDF profile, it produces the output PDF and give me back from the first page, it does not navigate to the place where I have done changes or the page where I left. Please help me out for this.

Comment: The preferred viewer for TXC2 is [Sumatra PDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/). In opposite to the Ad0be products it supports SyncTeX for forward and inverse search between source and PDF output.

Comment: Don't use adobe. Use e.g. sumatra if you need good syncing.

Comment: A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 2):

What you want to achieve is not possible with Adobe Acrobat or Reader. You have to use another PDF Viewer. The preferred alternative is [SumatraPDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/). For configuration see [How to configure TeXnicCenter 2.0 with Sumatra (2013--2016 version)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116981/).

From SumatraPDF you will have the opportunity to open the active document in Adobe Reader (or another installed PDF viewer) for documents with more complex contents, that will not be displayed with all features in SumatraPDF, but you are responsible then to close them by hand in the other viewer.

Comment: The problem is i have license version of adobe, so i dont want to use another pdf viewer for it. So does it mean that we can sync adobe and TeXnicCenter.

Comment: @Sunit_gupta: No, you cannot sync with Adobe. I also do not see your problem with a second _free_ PDF viewer, where you have the possibility to open the document in Adobe Acrobat.