# Inverse-search opens Notepad

Tags: texniccenter, texworks, sumatrapdf

I am using TeXnicCenter in combination with SumatraPDF and I have followed [these](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116981/how-to-configure-texniccenter-2-0-with-sumatra-2013-2014-2015-version) instructions.

However, the problem at my university is that I need to use a server-based version of TeXnicCenter, so I adjusted the executable path as follows (Profiles - Viewer);

```
H:\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe -inverse-search "\"H:\TeXworksPortable\TeXworksPortable.exe\" /ddecmd \"[goto('%f','%l')]\""
```

That is, when I double-click in the PDF file, I want to open TeXworksPortable to edit the .tex file. However, currently Notepad opens instead when I double-click inside the pdf file.

Comment: Do you have any news for us?